# How to prevent my image to shrink

Tags: html, css

When I shrink my browser window from left to right or from top to bottom, my image's aspect ratio changes. I'v tried to give my image an height in pixels but by doing so, the image hides my 'h3' sentence.

This is my code pen: [A tribute page - project](https://codepen.io/nadav-himmelfarb/pen/pVpZRG)

And this is a part of my code:

```
    header {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

    .container-fluid {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

 .row {
  height: 100%;
}


#image {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row, wrap;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ed1c24;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add to `#image` rule `object-fit: cover` but this solution doesn't work in IE. For IE you need to find a Polyfill.

Comment: It worked like magic but how can you find a 'Polyfill' for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Updated my answer: [**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/SirExotic/pen/jxKbaL)

Relevant code:

```
header {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9b/Red_Hot_Chili_Peppers_2012-07-02_001.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ed1c24;
}
```

When you put the image in the HTML as an `<img>` tag, you will experience some problems with the sizing. The fix is to use the image as a `background-image`, as I did above.

Look [**here**](https://codepen.io/SirExotic/pen/xjzGWp) for an example.

When resizing the window some space is added between `.headline-box` and the bottom of the header.

Comment: I don't know why but I don't see the image in your codepen. Maybe it got deleted. I tried to use this in may codepen and the image still shrinking.

Comment: @NadavHimmelfarb Can you take a look at my updated answer? I took the liberty to rework your whole website because I liked your design, but the code was really messy and unorganized. I hope you appreciate it, and if not, at least like the answer :) Good luck!

Comment: Wow man, I can't  wait to look at it, and of course! very cool from you men! Can you resend a link to the codepen ?

Comment: It's the first [link](https://codepen.io/SirExotic/pen/jxKbaL) in my updated answer. If you have any questions about a change I made, feel free to come back here and ask me about it.

Comment: < Feeling free :) I just started to check it and trying to get a clue on how to make my code better, lighter: (sorry if I'v a lot of questions, I'm less than a month with css) 1.why you used @import for the fonts and how do you know what is the url ? 2. why you deleted the " overflow-y: scroll" ?

Comment: I found the url :)

Comment: 3. Though I can find a reason, still, why you gave the logo flex-column ? 4. And how you can solve this "not a full image" issue in the background-image way ?

Comment: If you have many questions, maybe it's better to take it outside of Stack Overflow, so I can help you personally. I can give you my facebook or alternative social media if you wish.

Comment: What's your fb?